# Can someone please explain these Python string formatters

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-formatting

I am confused at the difference between the Python string formatters %d and %i. The Python manual page explains them as the same thing, '**signed integer decimal**' - confused !

[image: Python string formatters]

[From the Python 'Built in Types' page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: Why exactly are you confused? There are plenty of synonyms in Python 2.7 (e.g., `str` and `bytes`, or struct format prefixes `!` and `>`), and even more in English. Do you find those confusing? If you're asking _why_ there are synonyms, that's a reasonable question, but if you really can't figure out how to write your code or read someone's code because of them, I think you need to explain more what exactly the confusion is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the exact same thing.

Python inherited the syntax from C, where you can *also* use the same format in the `scanf()` function to parse input into variables. There you can then use `%i` to accept integers in hexadecimal format with a `0x` prefix, octal notation when preceded by `0`, as well as regular decimal (base 10) integers, while the `%d` formatter strictly only accepts decimal integer input.

On output with the `printf` function however, you'd use `%x` and `%o` to format output to hexadecimal and octal, explicitly, always, and `%d` and `%i` are merely synonymous and output decimal integers. Python inherited the `printf` formats wholesale, aliases and all, even though there is no equivalent for the `scanf` distinction.

See the [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and [`scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) manpages.

The newer [*Format Specification Mini-language*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) (used in both the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)) does away with the `i` formatter altogether; only `d` remains there.

Comment: Thanks - that clears it up. I didn't know if it was a typo on the Python doc page or they were indeed the same thing.